# How to change class style for children element by parent element id?

Tags: javascript

For example I have simple html code:

```
 <a id="news" href="#"><div class="" >News</div></a>
```

How to change class style for div element by id of href on pure javascript ?
Or may be better describe div properties in class for "a" element  ? ( How to do it ?)

Answer (score 14):

Since you're looking for the first `div` inside an element with an ID (which must be unique), your best bet is [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector), combined with either [`className`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className) (if you want to completely replace the entire content of the `class` attribute) or [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) (if you want to add/remove classes while leaving others unchanged):

```
// *Replacing* all existing classes with one new one
document.querySelector("#news > div").className = "example";

// *Adding* a class without replacing existing ones:
document.querySelector("#news > div").classList.add("example");
```

`querySelector` and `classList` are supported by all non-obsolete browsers (and many obsolete ones).

Alternatively, you can get a reference to your "news" element using [`getElementById`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-getElBId), then use [`getElementsByTagName`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-1938918D) to get the `div` elements within it:

```
// Replacing
document.getElementById("news").getElementsByTagName("div")[0].className = "example";

// Adding
document.getElementById("news").getElementsByTagName("div")[0].classList.add("example");
```

More to explore:

- [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web)
- [DOM3 Core specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/)
- [DOM2 HTML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/)
- [Selectors API specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api/)
- [HTML5 Web Applications API](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#webappapis)

Comment: Thank you very much. getElementsByTagName worked for me to get the child node

Comment: @ChristinaVarghese - Thanks for the comment, I need to update this answer, it's from 2012 and things have moved on. Here in 2023 I'd probably do `const div = document.querySelector("#news div");`.

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of ways to do it but assuming the direct structure above.

```
var new_class = "ClassName";
document.querySelector('a#news > div').setAttribute('class', new_class);
```

Of course if your browser doesn't support `querySelector` you'll have to do a bit more finagling like this

```
document.getElementById('news').childNodes[0].setAttribute( 'class', new_class );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can grab original element then children of node to edit the child node class

```
const link = document.querySelector('#news')
```

For Toggle class:

```
link.children[0].classList.toggle('example-class')
```

For add class:

```
link.children[0].classList.add('example-class')
```

For remove class:

```
link.children[0].classList.remove('example-class')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var newsA = document.getElementById('news');
var myDiv = newsA.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
myDiv.setAttribute('class', 'myClass');
```

That is one way.

To turn that into one nice line of code:

```
document.getElementById('news').getElementsByTagName('div')[0].setAttribute('class', 'myClass');
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use nth-child to select a child or childs of an elements..

```
const news = document.querySelector('#news')
news.querySelector('a:nth-child(1)').classList.add('example')
```

**You can repeat this for any childs you need**

```
news.querySelector('a:nth-child(2)').classList.add('example')
news.querySelector('a:nth-child(3)').classList.add('example')
```

Hope it will help someone :)

Answer (score -1):

As in HTML5, it is better to use dataset modifiers, like this:

```
.some-content[data-alt = "white"] {
    background: white;
}
```

and then in javascript:

```
someElement.dataset.alt = "white"
```