# Javascript Get column value from table

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I have the code below that returns the rowIndex of the clicked row.

The table uses the info from the WebViewString element, it has an csv formatted data and always have at least one column.

I need to get the value of the first column of that row. **How to???**

I know nothing about JS... just need this little modification but couldn't find anything by myself.

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
  <meta name="author" content="puravidaapps.com">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0">

  <!--Import materialize.css-->
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="materialize.min.css"  media="screen,projection"/>

  <title>Table Layout</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="myTable"></div>
  <script>
    // if you have commas inside your text, feel free to use another delimiter, for example |
    var delimiter = ",";

    // get the table to display from the window.AppInventor object and split at new line
    var urlArray = window.AppInventor.getWebViewString().split("\n");
    //var urlArray = location.search.slice(1).split("/n");

    var doc = document;
    var fragment = doc.createDocumentFragment();
    var thead = doc.createElement("thead");
    var tr = doc.createElement("tr");

    // split at delimiter
    var rowArray = urlArray[0].split(delimiter);

    addRow(thead, "th");
    fragment.appendChild(thead);

    var tbody = doc.createElement("tbody");
    for(i=1;i<urlArray.length;i++){
      var tr = doc.createElement("tr");

      // split at delimiter
      var rowArray = urlArray[i].split(delimiter);

      tr.addEventListener ("click", function () {
        // return index (add 1 because first row is the header row)
        // window.document.title = this.rowIndex + 1;
        window.AppInventor.setWebViewString(this.rowIndex + 1);
      });

      addRow(tbody, "td");
    }
    fragment.appendChild(tbody);
    var table = doc.createElement("table");
    table.appendChild(fragment);
    doc.getElementById("myTable").appendChild(table);

    // http://stackoverflow.com/a/9236195/1545993
    doc.getElementById("myTable").getElementsByTagName('table')[0].className = "striped";


    function addRow(dom, tag) {
      for(j=0;j<rowArray.length;j++){
        var el = doc.createElement(tag);
        el.innerHTML = rowArray[j];
        tr.appendChild(el);
        dom.appendChild(tr);
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Obviously you need to at least tell us WHERE in the given code is the logic you seek to modify ;)

Comment: All this code does is create the table. If you want a column just go through the rows and get the cell value of the first column.

Comment: Sorry, I tried to bold the line and I ended up removing the line of code... The line is **window.AppInventor.setWebViewString(this.rowIndex + 1);**